# Is there a way to avoid broken or untested code from going live using CI?

Tags: continuous-integration

I recently got my team to switch to CI. We're still in the baby steps, but so far we've started using [this branching strategy](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and it's been working great. We don't have any automated tests running yet and do all our testing manually. We are also currently doing weekly releases so we create a release branch from our Dev branch Monday afternoon, run further tests Tuesday and push it live to our Master branch on Wednesday morning and monitor through out the day. The problem is that sometimes our QA team doesn't get to test all our features in time or the feature fails QA, but is already in the Dev branch and could be going live prior to the issues being fixed. Any ways to mitigate this? This is all fairly new to us so I am open to changing everything if necessary.

Hopefully this diagram is a good explanation of how things work currently: 
[image: weekly release strategy]

Comment: So don’t even worry about code coverage (keyword) until automated testing is in place. Most CI systems will allow “failing when tests fail”. Ensuring code coverage (of new or existing code) is a layer in top.

Comment: Regarding the process: non-tested code (eg. if the process is manual) should stay on develop/QA branches and never be merged mainline. Then the develop/QA branches can be used to gate validated code, where only much smaller/quicker validation is done on the mainline branches. This will avoid pushing QA beyond their (the manual workflow) capacity. If it’s not validated, it’s not merged and thus not deployed. (In a proper CI setup the branches would have processes run against them blocking merges on test failure / quality issues / insufficient coverage.)

Comment: tldr; **If it’s not validated via appropriate testing (manual or otherwise), code should not be merged from feature branches onto the mainline and thus not deployed.** A CI system with branch checks is then enforcement of 1) keeping code from ‘bad’/untested branches from being merged mainline, and 2) ensuring the mainline branches did not regress.

Comment: Once this is adhered to there should be *minimal* issues discovered on a mainline. It such an issue is discovered the two primary options are to 1) hold back deployment to the “last good version” (use tags not branches for deployment targets), or 2) ensure a ‘bug fix’ is applied and validated prior to deployment as necessary (or even a ‘hot fix’  for already deployed code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing [Continuous Integration (CI)](https://www.thoughtworks.com/continuous-integration).

In CI you only have **one** branch (master/main/etc) - on which the CI tool operates - and maybe very short lived child branches that get merged into that branch, ideally in < 1 day. Pretty much synonymous with [trunk-based development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/).

In traditional CI breakages are normal, part of the process - bad changes are identified by the CI tool (one of the reasons you're using it to start with) **after** they are merged into the branch. Breakages [should be fixed ASAP](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html#FixBrokenBuildsImmediately) as they block the project's critical path. Unfortunately this requires human intervention, which can be a serious speed bump for larger projects.

There is also **gating CI**, which performs automated orchestrated verifications of the changes **prior** to merging them into the branch, rejecting those failing the verifications and automatically merging into the branch the successful ones, thus ensuring that the branch maintain a minimum quality level at all times. IMHO the only comfy and deterministic way to do integration, especially in larger scale projects. AFAIK only 2 such tools out there: [Zuul](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/) and [ApartCI](https://apartci.apartsw.com/) (which is my baby).

The QA/release stages are just subsequent steps in your CI/CD pipeline which are automatically reached if the previous steps pass, see the picture in [this answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/493/47). Optionally you can pull release branches from the respective refpoints, which would allow complex multi-releases stories, hot-fixes, etc. But these branches are **never** merged back into their parent, the hot-fixes are instead double-committed/cherry-picked   into the master branch, potentially with additional changes as required by the different branch context.

GitFlow is not CI:

- you have multiple branches (silos) which you only merge once in a while.
- branch merges can rapidly become a nightmare, especially in larger projects where you can have more than 1 feature branch active simultaneously. Try to add 1 then 2 more parallel feature branches in your picture, as well as the additional **upstream** branch merges that need to be performed **before** you can do the merges you already show. And the additional QA executions you may need because of these extra merges. Just to get an idea about how badly such strategy scales.
- tests done in these isolated branches are out of context - the branches do not reflect the overall project integration. Even if these tests pass the master branch may fail them or be plain broken after merge. See [an example](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/512/47) of how just 2 simple changes can cause such problems, let alone branches with multiple changes.

As you probably guessed by now, I'm not a big fan of GitFlow, it's awfully similar to the pre-CI integration practices I had to endure a long time ago ;)

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/10523/47